# I try to create a table into my database from python and I get an error

Tags: python, eclipse, oracle10g

I try to create tables with name of "data" variable into my database from python27 (PyDev in Eclipse). The Oracle statement I used is:

```
create_table="CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE " + data + """ (
 fk_id   number,
 DATA     VARCHAR(15),
 VENUE    VARCHAR(15),
 LOCATION VARCHAR(15)
 )"""
cursor.execute(create_table)
```

I get the

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
 File "D:\Stuffs\eclipse\scraper\ciorna.py", line 32, in <module>   
  cursor.execute(create_table) cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00922: 
missing or invalid option" on cursor.execute(create_table).
```

Someone can help me?
Why I get this error, what I've made wrong in my code?

Comment: What is stored in the data variable you are concatenating? i.e. + data +   And why the triple quotes around your schema?

Comment: I store in data variable strings (i.e names)!Triple quotes helps me extend my oracle sql statement on multiple lines!

Comment: Some basic troubleshooting should clear it up a bit. Remove the concatenation and put it all on one line and see if it works. create_table="CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE some_table ( fk_id NUMBER(10), DATA     VARCHAR(15), VENUE    VARCHAR(15), LOCATION VARCHAR(15)  )"

Comment: yes it works this way only with a fix table name,but I have this statement in a for loop and every time I have to create a table with other name,which is stored in data variable which changes with every iteration

Comment: how to make it works with table name=value of data variable?

Comment: My guess is the variable assignment is the issue:  Continue troubleshooting. Leave it as one line and try two lines:  x = "test_table" and then next line create_table="CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE" + x +  "( fk etc.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support `OR REPLACE` for tables.  Try this instead:

```
create_table="CREATE TABLE " + data + """ (
 fk_id   NUMBER(10),
 DATA     VARCHAR(15),
 VENUE    VARCHAR(15),
 LOCATION VARCHAR(15)
 )"""
```